# How to install specific kernel version on ubuntu, which disappeared already from repo `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

My current kernel version is "5.15.0-73-generic". There is some "leading" crypto company, which offers product to strenghten company machines, and our company bought their product without any sufficient PoC. Their product will only install with specific linux kernel, even below patch version, say 5.15.0.69-generic. They do not roll their own repo to contain all supported kernels, and this version, while it did exist at some point in past, it does not exist in `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` now.

While I probably can download some deb from some untrusted source on web, but I don't like doing this for sake of better security.

I tried to add:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
```

as source, but this does not exist (yet?). Can someone recommend some reasonably trusted source, which I can add as repo, which will contain *all* historic kernel versions?

Comment: I wouldn't advise to modify your Linux setup for one product. Ask rather this company for a version that supports the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: indeed, but our opinion has small power over bigger companies. I'd love to know what they are doing there so specific, that they cannot live with given major.minor.

Answer (score 0):

#### A specific case

You have to be **absolutely** sure about the *full* version numbering.

You can download e.g. from [here the 5.15.0.69.67](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/5.15.0.69.67) source packages, then compile and install on your system.

Note that if they deleted from the mainline it should had some problem... give it a look.

---

#### In general

Installing kernel versions other than the currently maintained ones can cause compatibility problems in different packages.

If it is not possible to request an update of the specific program (perhaps because for security reasons the software house cannot execute after each kernel loading to study, check, debug the code) it is advisable to *freeze* the kernel version with the latest compatible. This will probably force you to *freeze* the version of other packages as well.

To install an old kernel on an already uploaded system, in my experience, leads to a lot of compatibility issues that you will need to fix downgrading many packages and programs.

However, you can install the kernel version you want from the main kernel pipeline <sup>[[1](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)]</sup>.

Under ubuntu you may install a cosy script <sup>[[2](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh)]</sup> `ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh` e.g.

```
ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -r 5.15
```

to show all the available `5.15`.

You may want to follow other ways to install the kernel<sup>[[3](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/)]</sup> by downloading by hands the Linux deb packages etc etc...

---

#### Overkill... we like it!

An overkill solution may be to configure a frozen system virtual machine with that kernel for use only with the specific program.

Comment: Thanks for advices! Yes,I'm aware of all the problems coming with freezing and insisting on *deleted* version.Company selling security product doing this ... that is ehm-stupid-ehm. I hope I won't needed script you linked as running 1k LOC sh as root is ... I also found out,that sometimes deleted kernes is just moved to another cannonical repo, say from security to proposed, and so far this solves my issue. I hope I won't ever get to situation when it won't suffice. As I don't want to be forced to use that sh. But thanks for that, it's nice backup! And maybe someone else will write another way

Comment: It's not stupid _per se_: if you think about all the work time they have to spend on each  new kernel... and they might not also know in advance that a specific kernel will be removed etc. The bulk of the work is in the _rolling-back_ of the kernel. It's not said that you can just roll back all other packages and config files... So, if it's just for one program, that will probably still be stuck with the old kernel for a long time and that in the future be stuck with another version that may become obsolete itself... you may want to consider the "overkill" option (Virtual Machine dedicated).

Comment: maybe you are right. Sadly it's not for 1 program, but especially for whole system. I hardly believe, that they go over whole kernel source and say: "yes! this version is fine and covered, we support this." and do this all the way down to the sub-patch version. Major.minor must be more than enough. And if there is security hole but you cannot upgrade, because "security" company does not support newer kernel version yet, so you have nothing to upgrade to even if it's minimal change and new patch version exist immediately — I'd call this very detrimental if we want to avoid word stupid.